# Convert Map<String, String> to Map<String, List<String>> after GroupingBy

Tags: java, list, hashmap, java-stream

Need some help

How to convert

```
Map(String, String) to Map(String, List(String))
```

after `groupingBy`

Thanks in advance

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: item..entrySet()
      .stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(map -> map.getKey()));

but I don't get what I want

Comment: i have

{(a,1),(a,2),(a,3),(b,1),(b,2)}

i need

{ (a, {1,2,3}) , (b, {1,2}) }

Comment: It would be helpful if you would provide real java code, so we can see what you've tried, and so we can see what your input is. Your comment above seems to suggest the input is a map with repeated keys (a and b), which is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me try, I could solve it

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorry for the conceptual error, the conversion is from iterable to map with grouping

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RKeyDataRule {

    private int id;
    private int businessProcessId;
    private int xpathKeyDataId;

    public RKeyDataRule(int i, int j, int k) {
        this.id = i;
        this.businessProcessId = j;
        this.xpathKeyDataId = k;
    }
    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    /**
     * @return the businessProcessId
     */
    public int getBusinessProcessId() {
        return businessProcessId;
    }
    /**
     * @param businessProcessId the businessProcessId to set
     */
    public void setBusinessProcessId(int businessProcessId) {
        this.businessProcessId = businessProcessId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the xpathKeyDataId
     */
    public int getXpathKeyDataId() {
        return xpathKeyDataId;
    }
    /**
     * @param xpathKeyDataId the xpathKeyDataId to set
     */
    public void setXpathKeyDataId(int xpathKeyDataId) {
        this.xpathKeyDataId = xpathKeyDataId;
    }
}
```

#

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Iterable<RKeyDataRule> itrRKeyDataRule = Arrays.asList(
                new RKeyDataRule(1,1,1),
                new RKeyDataRule(2,1,2),
                new RKeyDataRule(3,1,3),
                new RKeyDataRule(4,1,4),
                new RKeyDataRule(5,1,5),
                new RKeyDataRule(6,2,6),
                new RKeyDataRule(7,2,7),
                new RKeyDataRule(8,2,8),
                new RKeyDataRule(9,2,9),
                new RKeyDataRule(10,2,10)
                );
        List<RKeyDataRule> lRKeyDataRule = new ArrayList<RKeyDataRule>();
        StreamSupport.stream(itrRKeyDataRule.spliterator(), false)
            .filter(rule -> rule.getXpathKeyDataId()%2==0)
            .forEach(lRKeyDataRule::add);

        Map<Integer, List<RKeyDataRule>> rKeyDataRuleGroupedByProc = lRKeyDataRule.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RKeyDataRule::getBusinessProcessId));

        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> procAndMainXpaths = new HashMap<>();
        for(Entry<Integer, List<RKeyDataRule>> entry : rKeyDataRuleGroupedByProc.entrySet()) {
            List<Integer> lmainXpaths = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            entry.getValue().stream().map(m -> m.getXpathKeyDataId()).forEach(lmainXpaths::add);
            procAndMainXpaths.put(entry.getKey(), lmainXpaths);
        }

        System.out.println(procAndMainXpaths);

    }

}
```

#

And the output

{1=[2, 4], 2=[6, 8, 10]}